# how to get transparent for the div?

Tags: css, html, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

Does CSS gives any option to show background image at the corner a `transparent`.

instead of showing white background in ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L8JUJ/4/))

**avoid white area**

[image]

```
#octagon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
}

#octagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 29px solid red;
    border-left: 29px solid red;
    border-right: 29px solid #eee;
    width: 42px;
    height: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L8JUJ/4/

Comment: u add style  opacity:0.6;

Comment: @Deepak Saralaya Actually no need to show white colour at all. Need to show bg

Comment: Basically, not possible. The pseudo element is contained **within** the primary object and so will always have the same background.

Comment: @Paulie_D is there any option make a shape at the corner and put `right: -20px`, show out side of the `div` !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/L8JUJ/6/)

Made small changes and adjustments in margins.

**CSS**:

```
body{
    background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar1) repeat;
}
#octagon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 71px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    margin: 99px 10px 0px 100px;
}

#octagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -29px;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 29px solid red;
    border-left: 29px solid red;
    border-right: 29px solid transparent;
    width: 42px;
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#octagon:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border-bottom: 29px solid red;
border-left: 29px solid red;
border-right: 29px solid #eee;
width: 42px;
height: 0;
opacity:0.6;
```

}

Comment: not syre this is cortect. yes it makes that corner transparent but not entirely. this allows the red to show through. I believe the OP wants to see the text bleed through...

Answer (score 0):

For a transparent border you can modify #octagon:before border-right with

```
border-right: 29px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

That will not give you the effect you want because in the back there is the element that already has a background color, so the only way to do this and work would be to add some js to your code, such as:
http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/